# How I can kill process of users on the network? Using the path

Tags: c#, kill-process

Guys I need to users close programm when I need it. So I can kill process by its name

```
 foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("eDoc"))
                {
                    proc.Kill();
                }
```

What should I do to kill process using path

```
\\hp\MyJob\eDoc.exe
```

Thanks so much

Comment: `Process `will kill only on local machine, you need to connect to the remote computer and invoke the kill command there, I think you do with via WMI

Comment: Maybe you find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727323/kill-process-on-remote-machine?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kill process on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727323/kill-process-on-remote-machine)