# How to handle any GUI program from my own java program?

Tags: java

This question may have been asked couple of times but I haven't found any solid answer. I want to write a program to run google chrome and write something in search box and search then click on the link with most similar word. Or a program to open microsoft office word and type something and change the size and etc. Or a program which open calculator and do some operation and bring back the result. I have done couple of things from command line like connecting to Oracle DB and importing and exporting the database. I know JDBC is like a interface. Is there any technology (with java or any other language) which can manage another program from it's GUI point of view?

Comment: Have you tried using AutoHotKey? Though it is not java based, it fits your requirement well.

Comment: *"This question may have been asked couple of times but I haven't found any solid answer."*  And not one of those answers so much as mentioned the `Robot`?  It is not good enough to 'make hand waving gestures' about doing research.  Indicate it in the question by detailing the results of that research and the conclusions or suspicions you drew from it.  Voting to close..

Comment: I have queried "java gui automation" in google and guess what? Try Firefox, may be your Chrome spoils good search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can write one in C# for windows
2. you can use `spy++` (it should be installed or it comes with visual studio... not sure about this) to see what component you are searching for(it's like firebug for windows)
3. You can use `user32.dll` to find window and send a message(user clicked, user pressed, etc)

but if you want to copy webpages or search in them.. you should make REQUESTs to google and read the response as text...

Answer (score 0):

For web browser you can use [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).
Not sure about other things.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) and make calls to you OS API.

I the case of Windows, you can have a look at `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx`, `FindWindowByCaption` to make the lookup of the element you want.
Then, use `sendMessage` to simulate windows events such as key types, mouse clicked...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248444/how-to-close-window-by-its-name) is an example in C# showing how to close a window by its name in C#. It shouldn't be too hard to translate it into Java by using JPA. (Have also a look in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) page)