# How to suppress Windows warning of corrupted files when trying to open the file in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to open a file from a USB-Drive in my c# application. I handle the IOException in C# If the file is corrupted. Unfortunately also Windows 10 is showing a message box which I want to suppress.

```
try
{
  // Open file and read all lines to trigger the exception if file is bad
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(s);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  // Corrupted File found Execute CHKDSK on that drive
}
```

C# is handling the exception as expected. But Windows is showing the following message:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress the Windows warning window?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe run the CheckDisk utility?

Comment: What is the exception type when that message is shown?

Comment: The exeption I catch in C# has the following stack trace: 
"at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.IO.Stream...

Comment: The Windows warning is not coming out of my C# Application - it is opened by Windows it self.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to find the Windows message window by title and close it this way: [How to close the window by its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248444/how-to-close-the-window-by-its-name)

It is working but it is a hack. Any other solutions are highly welcome.

Comment: Suppressing this critical error is quite unwise, especially so for USB memory sticks.  https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/11/half_plug_in_found_drives/

Answer (score 1):

Your program is running into a corrupt file or disk. It's probably best to run the [`chkdsk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) utility on the disk. However, if you want your application to not get stuck on the hard error, you can disable Windows from showing a message box.

In order to do so, you'll need to disable hard error message boxes for your process. Call the Windows API function [`SetErrorMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) using [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

```cs
[Flags]
public enum ErrorMode : UInt32 {
    Default                   = 0x0,
    SemFailCriticalErrors     = 0x0001,
    SemNoGpFaultErrorBox      = 0x0002,
    SemNoAlignmentFaultExcept = 0x0004,
    SemNoOpenFileErrorBox     = 0x8000
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern ErrorMode SetErrorMode(ErrorMode uMode);
```

Then you can call the function early in your program (like `Main`) like so

```cs
SetErrorMode(ErrorMode.SemFailCriticalErrors);
```