# Killing of running process in window with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How we can kill the other running process in window with VB.NET 2.0 framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You and simply kill the process by kill() method.

```
    Dim processList() As Process
    processList = Process.GetProcessesByName(ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString)

    For Each proc As Process In processList
        If MsgBox("Terminate " & proc.ProcessName & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Terminate?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Try
                proc.Kill()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Kill all instances of notepad:

```
Process.GetProcessesByname("Notepad").ForEach(Sub(x) x.Kill())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) to accomplish this. You can find the answer as well on [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c) (both C# as VB.NET answers).

Look at the [MSDN Page: Process.Kill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) for some more details.

Here is a code sample how to use it (took it parts from MSDN):

```
' First find the process(es) you want to kill, for example searching for the name
Dim notepadProcesses As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")

' Loop over the array to kill all the processes (using the Kill method)
Array.ForEach(notepadProcesses, Sub(p As Process) p.Kill())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **get process name** using `Process.GetProcessesByName Method` and **kill it** using `Process.Kill Method`.

**Example:**

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("mspaint");

foreach (Process process in processes){
 process.Kill();
}
```

***MSDN Entries:***

**[MSDN - Process.Kill Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx#Y0)**

**[MSDN - Process.GetProcessesByName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx)**

***Similar SO question:***

**[How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

1st create a a.bat file and store it into bin or in your project folder
In batch file write following line

```
tskill (your process name)
```

save it as .bat

in coding write following line

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Your bat file path")
```