# How do I kill a process, given the title of a form hosted in that process?

Tags: c#, process

How do I kill a process, given the title of a form hosted in that process?

how to kill the program runs as system retired. While I only had the title of it?

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: We are not GOOGLE, kindly find your one liner answers in GOOGLE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are trying to close your form. If so then you can use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property and get the form based on the title like:

```
var form = Application.OpenForms
                      .Cast<Form>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Text == "YourTitle");
if(form != null)
    form.Close();
```

*You should consider that there could be multiple forms for same title.*

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment ?

Comment: I've been downvoted before for answering a horrible question. Perhaps your downvoter did the same?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, if that is the case then I will be surprised at the [reversal badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) in SO :)

Comment: how to kill the program runs as system retired. While I only had the title of it?