# how to kill/ close a .exe after having opened it

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net I have used `process.start` to open a .exe file and then have a `threading.thread.sleep` after it for an amount of time. Then I want it to close the .exe file but it won't let me use `process.kill`/`close`.

code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("notepad.exe")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Process.Kill()
```

Comment: what error you are getting!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)

Answer (score 1):

You need to you the object which is referencing the handle for process. here is the example

```
Dim p As Process = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
p.Kill()
```