# Killing MS Office process in VB.NET without losing unsaved changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

[How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)

The above thread lead to a question.  If we want VB to kill a word process, is there a way to ensure that no changes will be lost?  I.e. the following pseudocode

```
if (Word has no unsaved changes)
Then kill Word
Else
Open Dialog to save progress
kill Word
```

Comment: That isn't how you do it. If you want to save changes, you *ask nicely* for the process to quit. You don't kill it.

Comment: Thank you. Am new to VB.NET and was curious.  Answer is provided in the thread mentioned.