# Close a windows process in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application, I started a process say chrome via the command`

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
```

Now I want to close this current process. What should I code so as to close just this chrome application.

Comment: Simply [Kill()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx) the `Process` instance you get from `Process.Start()`?

Comment: `Process.Start` is a function which returns a `Process`. Choose the appropriate method from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to close it. I suppose that the user might have opened more windows or tabs, seeing as it is a browser that you have started..

Comment: @Filburt Kill might be a bit harsh: "Kill causes an abnormal process termination, and should be used only when necessary." CloseMainWindow seems more reasonable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It did fit well in the comment context and should mainly serve to point the OP to MSDN.

Comment: @Andrew Morton -s .CloseMainWindow() is much more elegant, should be posted as Answer.

Comment: @CLS Following the comments to the [answer by Anderson Pimentel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564807/1115360), which included CloseMainWindow, I am not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out on comments, just call the `Kill()` method on the instance returned by `Process.Start('...')`.

```
var myProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");

//Do your stuff...

myProcess.Kill();
```

Also, take a look at MSDN about a (maybe) better way to terminate the process: [`CloseMainWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT:**

To kill an arbitrary process take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c) question.

Comment: I mean I just want to close an already running process. That is, I just want to close an uninstantiated process.Like, I opened chrome in my pc and I want my program to close it.

Comment: @AbhishekTrigunait That is a totally different question. You asked about a process you started using `Process.Start()`.

Comment: @AbhishekTrigunait Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Thanks, that helped. Is there a way to close the current program with getCurrentProcess or something...