# Killing other applications Window

Tags: vb.net, windows-server

I have the problem, I'm in a network, where everyone sends messages through [msg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg). Through it's really annoying, I thought about killing the messageboxes process. Running under csrss.exe thats not possible. When I looked through the taskmanager I noticed, when opening the tree structure of the csrss.exe, there was the messagebox and I could kill it. Has anyone any idea, how to do that in Visual Basic.

Comment: What is `msg` exactly?

Comment: @djv https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg

Comment: You can try with UI Automation, using a `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent`. Get the processID of the `csrss.exe` processes and when you're notified that a new Window is opened, compare the Window processID with the ones you've stored and close the Window if it's a match. To close a Window, you need to get the WindowPatter of the Automation element and use its Close() method (e.g., `Dim pattern As object = Nothing) If [Element].TryGetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern, pattern) Then dim wPattern = DirectCast(pattern, WindowPattern) wPattern.Close() end if`.

Comment: You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505218/7444103) a VB.Net implementation of a `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` notification. Btw, I never tested in this scenario, so take it *as is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so the question hast a proper answer, I found a solution using the win32 api ([PInvokes](https://pinvoke.net/)) specifically the user32.dll. It provides methods like `GetWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `CloseWindow`, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple web search led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116090/832052), which has some good answers already.

With a little work, I came up with this solution. It find the process by name (*csrss*), then filters by window title (*Message from*).

```vb
Sub Main()
    killProcesses("csrss", "Message from")
End Sub

Private Sub killProcesses(processName As String, mainWindowTitle As String)
    Dim processes = Process.GetProcesses().
        Where(Function(p) p.ProcessName.Contains(processName)).
        Where(Function(p) p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(mainWindowTitle))
    '  (Where clauses can be combined into one of course)
    For Each p In processes
        p.CloseMainWindow()
    Next
End Sub
```

It works like this. Send a message

> C:\Users\djv>msg djv hey whats up

Get a message

[image]

Here is the task

[image]

And what the code sees

[image]

It is closed upon the `p.CloseMainWindow()` call. It will also close any other window which matches the description, since it's not limited to one. This should satisfy your requirement.